# How .Net checks array boundaries without reducing the performance?

Tags: .net, arrays

How does .Net check array boundaries without a significant performance impact?

I want to use this technique in C and C++ codes.

Comment: Why do you think that checking the boundaries would not reduce perforomance?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Checking array boundaries reduce the performance in LOOPs.

Comment: But you have argued that C# would check boundaries _without_ reducing the performance.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Because C# is fast as C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several techniques you can use to check array boundaries while minimizing the performance impact:

1. By doing an unsigned comparison, you only have to check against the upper bound of the array (the lower bound is always 0).
2. Once you have checked an array bound against a variable that hasn't changed, you don't need to check it again. For exapmle, if you have `a[i] = a[i] + 1`, you only need to check `i` once even though the array is accessed twice.
3. When you know that an array index variable will never exceed the bounds of the array, you don't need to ever check. For example, if you have `for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) a[i] = 0;`, you know that `i` will always be a valid index into array `a` and it doesn't need to be checked.

Answer (score 1):

Checking boundaries is just doing a simple comparison, which is super fast but it of course has an impact on performance (as its doing something else). Something like this would occur before each set:

```
if (array.Length <= i)
    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("...");
```